# How to pass mock object to enzyme simulate function?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component which mainly returns html. All codes are simplified to address the issue.

```js
//MainRender.js
const clientId = 8;
const clientName = "Foo";

export default function MainRender(props){
  const theValue = props.value;
  function changeOnClick(elem, id, name){
    return (
      // elem: HTMLImgElement which triggers other event
      // id: number
      // name: string
      console.log(elem, id, name); 
    )
  };
    
  function helper1(arg) {
    return (
      <div className="helper1" onClick={(e) => changeOnClick(e.target.value, clientId, clientName)}>
        <span> Helper1: {arg.isHelper1} </span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function helper2(arg) {
    return (
      <div className="helper2" >
        <span> Helper2: {arg.isHelper2} </span>
      </div>
  )};

  if(theValue.isHelper1){
    return helper1(theValue)
  } else {
    return helper2(theValue)
  }
 };
```

and my test is,

```js
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

import MainRender from './MainRender';

describe("Testing MainRender", () => {
  it("it should return true when click is fired", ()=> {
    const tempValue = {"value": {"isHelper1":true, "isHelper2": false}};
    const wrapper = mount(<MainRender {...tempValue} />); 
    const helper1 = wrapper.find('.helper1');
    const spyElem = jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
    const mockElem = document.createElement('img');
    spyElem.mockReturnValue(mockElem);
    const mockHelper1 = jest.spyOn(MainRender, 'changeOnClick');
    

    helper1.simulate('click', {target: {elem:spyElem, id:7, name:'foo'});
    expect(mockHelper1.toHaveBeenCalled()).toBe(true);
 }
});
```

I just want to test the onClick function is actually called. I have been reading and researching the documents and examples about `jest` and `enzyme` but I am not sure I create correct mock HTML element that I keep getting error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined
```

How can I create mock Element and check the click event?
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You are passing module scope variables `clientId` and `clientName` to `changeOnClick` function.  Besides, `changeOnClick` is a private function declare in the function component, you can't get it from the test file so that you can't spy it. From your code, you can spy on the `console.log` method, check it is called or not. This will indirectly indicate whether the click event handler has been called

Comment: @slideshowp2 It actually has different function than `console.log`. I simplified code in here for posting